# UWP javascript crashes

Tags: javascript, uwp, crash

I am using UWP javascript application on VS2017. Each time there is a javascript exception the application crashes. The reproducible steps are
1.Open VS2017
2. Select Javascript from installed templated menu
3. select Blank App(Universal windows)

Now inside the JS project, write code that can exception, For Example:

```
var t;
console.log(t.length) //t is undefined, so t.length will cause an error
```

My questions are mentioned below:

1. Is there a way we can avoid these crashes like how ios and android does
2. Where can we find crash dumps for these. I have enabled crash dumps using the URL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps?redirectedfrom=MSDN). But I can only native/managed crashes(like C++, C#) but not javascript crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create WinJs App, which provides the life cycle management of the application `WinJS.Application`, the onerror event is provided to handle uncaught errors in the application.

You can handle the event here and tell the application that you have handled the exception by means of `return true`, then the application will not terminate.

```js
var app = WinJS.Application;
app.onerror = function (args) {
    console.log(args.detail.error);
    return true;
};
```

Comment: Thanks Richard!, This worked for me on my sample proj. Will try to use it on my actual work. Does it mean by adding this,  UWP will not crash for all JS exceptions and there is no need to look into crash logs generated if any for these exceptions.

Comment: Hello, the cause of the app crash is more than the error uncaught. The main purpose of listening to the `onerror` event globally is to catch errors and handle them. Errors raised during application operation should be analyzed and repaired, which helps to create a well-functioning program.

Comment: Ok, definitely onerror handler is where I handle exceptions. But what I wanted to know was when this kind of unhandled exceptions used to occur, I never was able to retrieve the stacktrace in user-mode-dumps. That was my question. Thanks anyways

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT - what causes this crash? I do not see this on other devices that use JS runtimes? This seems very specific to UWP (JS).

Comment: didnt help in my case whole release app still crashing if any javascript error occur. When debugging error is cougth by onerror func but it still closes the app